# Recessed light placement

Tags: recessed-lighting, interior

Is this good placement for 4 inch recessed lights in bedroom ?

Size of bedroom  is 15' × 11'. Distance between each dot is 1 feet.

Yellow line show king bed size. Red dots show recessed lights. Ceiling height is 8 feet.

I want to avoid light directly overhead when sleeping.
Open to suggestions though.

[image: placement]

Comment: Note that recessed "cans" tend to throw more downward than outward -- is there a particular reason you want that effect in a bedroom?

Comment: Recessed lights tend to let more sound through than surface mount lights. Do you have rooms above these lights?

Comment: Each light manufacturer has an output coverage rating for their lights. Have you checked their lighting diagram? Also, because the light will be “down”, they will leave dark areas in corners, etc.

Comment: This is 2nd floor condominium. There is a 3rd floor unit above my unit. Sound wasnt my concern. Just wanted to avoid lights directly over head when sleeping

Comment: It looks like you are planning to install **six** lights in a space 3' across and 1 1/2' deep... that's a lot of lights in a very small area.

Comment: Do you have nightstands with lights on them? Even without these, your plan strikes me as too much lighting, unless you put them on a dimmer...